# how to catch this event that when i left click and then move some where (not drag some div ) on a div 

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

this is my code:

```
$('#handle').mousedown(function(e){
if( (!$.browser.msie && e.button == 0) || ($.browser.msie && e.button == 1) ) {
       alert("Left Button");
    }
})
```

this event is like to drag , but not drag ,

the left button Has been pressed, no released until mouseup,

so how to catch  it using jquery ,

this is my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ATZNW/1/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't do this out of the box but you can fire your own events. Instead of alerting "left button", set some global variable `dragging` to true. Then:

```
$("#handle").mousemove(function (e) {
   if (dragging) {
      $(this).trigger("dragmove");
      // Or just write the code you need here
   }
});
```

Then you can handle that event elsewhere if you wish:

```
$("#handle").bind("dragmove", function (e) {

});
```